# Error de compatibilidad con 64 bits al publicar app en Google Play

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

He creado una app en flutter pero subirla a google play me esta dando un error que dice que mi app debe ser compatible con dispositivos de 64 bits. A pesar que dice que debe serlo en un futuro, aun no me permite publicarla. No entiendo por que y necesito ayuda en este proceso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revisa este hilo para más info : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18494

Comment: me da un error distinto, lo publico@diegoveloper